# Null reference exception unhandled when trying to assign a session var

Tags: vb.net, session-variables, nullreferenceexception, httpcontext

Code:

```
InitializeComponent()

HttpContext.Current.Session("Priority") = "Medium"
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to set up and assign a session var:

> Null Reference Exception Error

I've included `System.Web` as a reference in my program. I've tried using `InitializeComponent` first. I've tried using `Session("Priority")` without the `HttpContext.Current` in front of it but that won't even compile.

Comment: Maybe HttpContext.Current is null. Since I'm seeing a InitializeComponent in there, seems like it's not a web application. If that is the case, no session.

Comment: @the_lotus, you're right, I had initially done this program in C# as a web application, then translated it to VB forms application.  So there wouldn't be a session.  That makes sense.

Comment: I found another link on stack overflow saying the thing to do for a Windows Forms application  Create a Static class that holds the User name and password and any other variables needed across the application .

Comment: A Session is just a global dictionary with a timeout.